# Ideals of type $\{m \in \mathbb Z\mid m^r \in \ n \mathbb Z \text{ for some } r\ge1\}$ in $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> For any integer $n$, let $I_n$ denote the ideal $\{m \in \mathbb Z \mid \exists r\in\mathbb N \text{ such that } m^r \in \ n \mathbb Z\}$. I want to know cardinality of $\frac{\mathbb Z}{I_{63} \cap I_{84}}$.

My attempt:
Clearly $63 \mathbb Z \subset  I_{63}$ and $84 \mathbb Z \subset  I_{84}$.

Can I say ${I_{63} \cap I_{84}}= I_{l.c.m. \{63,84\}}$? I am stuck here. Please help.

Comment: You should try to give a precise definition of $I_n$ in terms of $n$.  As a hint, start with $n\leq 13$ and think about the prime factorization of $n$.  Also remember that every ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is principal, so you already know $I_n = a\mathbb{Z}$ for some $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, now i can answer of my question.

$63 = 7 \times 3^2$

Distinct prime divisors of $63$ are $7$ and $3$ so $I_{63}= {21 \mathbb Z}$ because $3 \mathbb Z \supset I_{63}, 7\mathbb Z \supset I_{63}$ and $\mathbb Z$ is principal ideal domain.

Similarly $I_{84}= (2\times 3 \times7)\mathbb Z={42}\mathbb Z$.

Hence $I_{63} \cap I_{84}={42}\mathbb Z$

Also $I_{63} \cap I_{84}= I_{l.c.m. \{63,84\}}=I_{252} ={42} \mathbb Z $

So cadinality of required set $\frac{\mathbb Z}{I_{63} \cap I_{84}}$ is $42$.

Comment: Your final conclusion is fine, but you have a couple errors.  First we'd have $I_{63} \subset 3\mathbb{Z}$, not the other way around (similarly with $7\mathbb{Z}$).  Second, when you've written $I_{\gcd\{63,84\}}$, you should have written $I_{\operatorname{lcm}\{63,84\}}$.  In case you have not seen the topic yet, you should compare this to the [radical of an ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal).

Comment: Thak you correcting me